# Download infinitely scrolling webpage chunk by chunk (Selenium/PhantomJS)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am using Selenium with PhantomJS to scroll to the bottom of an infinitely scrolling page of Twitter search results.

```
 driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

I manually set a number of times for it too loop (I try to estimate how many reloads the web driver can take before crashing). When done, I grab the raw html:

```
text_file.write(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
```

This works ok, but I am looking for a way to keep the program going without the 'browser cache', or whatever it is called, filling up. Any ideas on how to achieve the steps below?

1. Run the `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`command for X times
2. Then dump the loaded raw html to a text file
3. Then run the driver for X times again
4. Then dump the loaded raw html into another text file, but not the content loaded in step 1, only the new content loaded in step 3

This would empty the browser/driver memory into several output text files and make it possible for the loop to practically go on forever. Any ideas?

Comment: Write a double loop: inside the inner loop, run the scroll command x times, grab the raw html, and write it to a .txt; in the outer loop, run the inner loop how ever many times you want.

Comment: If the site doesn't support starting from a later position (like page), then it is impossible to solve this.

Comment: I already tried what @JonathanEpstein is suggesting, but in this case it (1) dumps the first html; (2) dumps the first and second html; (3) dumps the first, second and third html.

Comment: So @ArtjomB. is right!